# Play WAV files in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-audio, wav

I am stuck on trying to make IE to play a WAV file. I have only WAV files (a big amount) and can't convert them because of server disk space.

On W3Schools it is stated that IE doesn't support WAV format for HTML5 `<audio>` tag. (I tried - really doesn't).

I have tried it with `mediaelement.js` and `jPlayer` - none of them present the pure solution. `mediaelement.js` just doesn't play it and `jPlayer` simply needs mp3.

I would like to omit using QuickTime plugin as users rarely have it and it's really frustrating to get a plugin missing error.

Is there any other way to play it?

Comment: Convert to a more compact lossless format then just delete the wav?

Comment: The records amount is in range of dozens of thousands. i suppose it will really influence badly on server and i really don't want to do that only because IE. Anyway, what  compact lose-less  format you can advise, that will have a support in all browsers? guess for now it doesn't exist((

Comment: w3schools.com is an [unreliable source](http://www.w3fools.com/) and should be avoided.

Comment: anyway, I have checked it on my own too

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the bgsound tag (only available for IE). The thing about bgsound is that it pretty much just autoplays, so only set the source when you want to play the file.

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play5.htm

Explore that site, they also mention several other methods you can try using, including a wav-compatable Flash player.